# Azure SDK for .Net - dependency injection for two subscriptions

Tags: .net-core, dependency-injection, azure-sdk-.net

I have the following code that registers an instance to the .net services collection for Azure services.

```
services.AddSingleton(x => Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent.Azure.Authenticate(azureCredentials)
             .WithSubscription(Configuration[ConfigurationConstants.AzureAuth_SubscriptionId]));
```

This code then resolves an instance of the `IAzure` in my service class where I can access all the services available like `_azure.SqlServers.ListAsync` etc.

I want to have a way so I can work with two Azure subscriptions and thus register two instances to the services collection and then be able to resolve the one that I want. You can check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/azure/sdk/dependency-injection#configure-multiple-service-clients-with-different-names) for a similar example of what I want, it's about the blob storage though.

Comment: As with the linked example, you would need a way to uniquely differentiate the services and most likely need to use a factory pattern design

Comment: The subscription Id could be used to separate the services, but that would require getting the current subscription from the service to find the match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with the linked example, you would need a way to uniquely differentiate the services and most likely need to use a factory pattern design

```
public interface IAzureFactory {
    IAzure GetSubscription(string subscriptionId);
}
```

The subscription Id could be used to separate the services, but that would require getting the current subscription id from the service to find the match

```
public class AzureFactory : IAzureFactory {
    private readonly IEnumerable<IAzure> subs;

    public AzureFactory (IEnumerable<IAzure> subs) {
        this.subs = subs;
    }

    public IAzure GetSubscription(string subscriptionId) {
        return subs.FirstOrDefault(_ => _.SubscriptionId == subscriptionId) ??
            throw new InvalidArgumentException("invalid subscription Id)"; 
    }
}
```

From there it is only a matter of registering the different subscriptions.

```
services.AddSingleton<IAzureFactory, AzureFactory>();

services
    .AddSingleton(x => Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent.Azure.Authenticate(azureCredentials)
         .WithSubscription(Configuration[ConfigurationConstants.AzureAuth_SubscriptionId1]));

services
    .AddSingleton(x => Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent.Azure.Authenticate(azureCredentials)
         .WithSubscription(Configuration[ConfigurationConstants.AzureAuth_SubscriptionId2]));
```

And using the factory to get the desired subscription

```
//...

private readonly IAzure azure;

//ctor
public MyService(IAzureFactory factory) {
    azure = factory.GetSubscription(...);
}

//...
```